# SharePoint SQL Services Reporting Services Report Viewer - print button option not available in Chrome Browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I have a SharePoint 2013 site and configured SQL Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated mode to work with SharePoint . it works fine without any issues . but the print option is not available in the Chrome Browser , the same is available with IE , here most of the users are using Chrome browser . How can I get the print option enabled in Report Viewer web part in Chrome browser.

In IE :

[image]

In Chrome :

[image]

I have enabled **Enable Client Printing** option from **Central Admin Service Application settings** as well as from Site Collection **Report Services Site Settings**.

Its given as ActiveX control , only IE Supports ActiveX controls but , how we can get this option in other browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this very much depends on the version of SQL Server Reporting Services being used, which you haven't mentioned.

In the upcoming [SQL Server 2016 version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/browser-support-for-reporting-services-and-power-view), Chrome is a fully supported browser for interacting with Reporting Services.

However for earlier versions, the only non-IE browsers supported (or at least partially supported) are Firefox and Safari. Older versions support progressively fewer features for non-IE browsers.

This means unless you have SQL Server 2016, using Chrome for reporting services is going to mean compatibility issues. To work around this there are a couple of possible solutions:

1) In a corporate environment, consider using the [Legacy Browser Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en) extension for Chrome - this requires Group Policy settings to force some URLs to open in an IE window.

2) Use the [IE Tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) in Chrome to render certain sites using the IE rendering engine, but inside a Chrome tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply on this , will check this suggested ways and update back the results , hope it'll solve my issue.

Comment: IE Tab Extension works perfectly which opens the required url in IE Compatible window in Chrome itself .

Comment: @Esaki Your welcome :))

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This is not supported in other web browsers apart from IE. You can see the links below for some workarounds

[SSRS print button in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208457/ssrs-print-button-in-chrome-and-firefox)

[SQL Reporting Services - Print Button not shown in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951009/sql-reporting-services-print-button-not-shown-in-mozilla)

Check both of this link

Comment: A lot of different things only work properly in IE. There are several workarounds posted in different places that you may want to try.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-and-date-picker-in-SSRS-reports-for-n